# How to replicate excel's pivot tables in .net with wpf?

Tags: .net, wpf, pivot-table

I've been working on an excel file which reads data from SQL databases and provides useful pivot tables from that data. I've now  reached a point where I need more control, so I was wondering if I could use my skills in vb.net to create an application instead of using an excel file.

I'd like to create the application using WPF, which provides the rich interface I'm looking for.

I've been learning about the MVVM pattern but now I've reached a point where I'm too confused!
The purpose of this question is to ask if someone could point me the right direction, the skills I'd need to have to accomplish my goals, etc.

Is my question too vague and hard to answer?

Comment: Well i would help if we'd know what makes you confused. Also i think, this question is a little too broad and im quite sure you will hardly achieve your goal with plain WPF

Comment: Hi lokusking...to tell you the truth, i was looking for something like this: http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx#extensive-set-of-controls